# ttl::variant, placement new

Tags: c++

I'm using the variant type from the ["Tiny Template Library"](http://tinytl.sourceforge.net/). The Variant is defined as:

```
template< TTL_TPARAMS_DEF(TTL_MAX_TYPELIST_PARAMS, empty_type) >
struct variant
{
    typedef variant this_t;
    typedef meta::typelist< TTL_ARGS(TTL_MAX_TYPELIST_PARAMS) > list;
    ...

    template< typename T >
    variant( const T& r ) : which_(0), pnt_(0)
    {
        typedef meta::find_equivalent_type<const T&, list> found;
        pnt_ = new(stor_.buf_) ttl::data_holder<typename found::type>(r);
        which_ = found::index;
    }
    ...
private:
    template<int N> 
    struct storage
    {
        union
        {
            ttl::data_holder_base dummy;  //hope to satisfy alignment settings
            char buf_[N];
        };
    };

    int which_;
    ttl::data_holder_base* pnt_;
    storage< sizeof(ttl::data_holder<typename list::largest_type>) > stor_;
    ....
};


struct data_holder_base {};

template< typename T >
struct data_holder : data_holder_base
{
    ...
    typedef const T& param_type;

    T d;
    ...
    data_holder( param_type d_ ) : d(d_) {}
    ...
};
```

When I send an object of this type over the network and "reconstruct" it using "memcpy" it is obvious thet the pointer "pnt_" will point to Nirvana. Due to the fact that I know the type that is stored I try to rebuild the pointer "pnt_" using a cast:

```
template<typename T>
inline void rebuild()
{
    pnt_ = reinterpret_cast<ttl::data_holder<T>*>(stor_.buf_); 
}
```

For the case I checked this example it works. But I don't know how the placement new (`pnt_ = new(stor_.buf_) ...`) is placing the object into `stor_.buf_`. 
Would it be required to store something like `std::distance(&stor_.buf_[0], pnt_)` to find the object?

Or is there a different way to get `pnt_` back?

Thank you
  Mario

Answer (score 0):

Placement `new` puts the new object in `stor_.buf_` because that's how placement `new` is defined to work. You give `new` the address of the memory you want it to use, and it constructs the object in that location. It returns the very same address, so the address stored in `pnt_` is that of `stor_.buf_`, but with the type of the constructed object, `ttl::data_holder<found::type>`, instead of `char*`. Since the addresses are the same, the `std::distance` value you mention would always be zero (assuming the call would even compile, which it won't because the argument types are different).

The address of `stor_.buf_` will also always be equal to that of `stor_.dummy`. You could make your added code simpler by assigning `pnt_` like this:

```
pnt_ = &stor_.dummy;
```

However, since you've apparently just copied raw memory over the socket, fixing up the internals of this `variant` object is only the tip of the iceberg. The value that your variant holds might *also* contain addresses, and you have no way of reaching inside that. Even if you do, the address you need might not be available. You were lucky with `variant` that the address you're fixing happens to be an address within the same object, so it's easy to compute. But consider `std::string`, which allocates memory from the free store; sending one over a socket won't give you anything usable on the other end — it might not even give you the character data at all. You should instead pursue some other technique for serializing and deserializing `ttl::variant` objects. You could post a question on Stack Overflow asking how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the additional pointers. This is not a problem in my application. Yeah, getting the address of dummy is simpler and I don't need any ugly cast...Thank you!